# United States - Does this bike lock legally qualify as a "booby trap"?

Tags: united-states, liability

I recently saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gP9wLJhaBOE) by LockPickingLawyer on Youtube, where he discusses a bicycle lock called the SkunkLock. This bike lock's shackle is filled with a vomit-inducing gas pressurized to 150 PSI. He mentions in the video that this lock would likely be considered illegal in most jurisdictions because it would likely qualify as a "booby trap".

Now I know he's actually a lawyer and I'm... well, not, but I am inclined to question the validity of his statement.

First off, the lock itself has "SKUNKLOCK" in large letters along the lock body, which is a pretty good indication of what the lock does. But okay, I can see a lawyer arguing that it's not really a warning label.

Secondly, at 13 seconds into the video, you can see a proper warning sticker on the shackle of the lock that says `WARNING: Do not puncture. Chemicals under pressure.`.

So given that the lock actually has a warning label on it telling you what will happen if you cut the shackle, doesn't that mean it's **not** a booby trap? I would think that in order to legally be considered a booby trap, it would need to have an element of surprise.

If it's **still** considered a booby trap even with the warning label, then wouldn't someone be able to, for example, come into your house, grab a bottle of Pine-Sol (lemon-scented surface cleaner) from your cleaning supplies closet/cabinet, drink it until they vomit, and then accuse you of setting a booby trap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Criminal codes vary, and even federal definitions often only apply in certain limited circumstances, so it's impossible to give a single clear answer to this.

**21 USC § 841(d)** is very narrowly about booby traps on federal property where controlled substances are being handled, but it gives us *one* definition of "booby trap" that a lot of states seem to have adopted:

> ...any concealed or camouflaged device designed to cause bodily injury when triggered by any action of any unsuspecting person making contact with the device. Such term includes guns, ammunition, or explosive devices attached to tripwires or other triggering mechanisms, sharpened stakes, and lines or wires with hooks attached.

California's penal code uses that same definition, with some slight modifications to the wording (they refer to *great* bodily injury, and change 'making contact' to 'coming across', since light-based triggers may not require contact).

Going by that definition, the Skunklock *probably* would not count because it isn't designed to cause "great bodily injury", and the warning label probably does give it some protection on the "unsuspecting person" side, since it did clearly state that it's a pressurized device (providing the owner didn't remove or conceal that label).

That said, I don't know that this is a particularly well-explored point of law, so you could possibly be in a big legal mess for a long time, even if it ended up *eventually* deciding that the device isn't a booby trap, so it might be better to avoid that whole issue.

Comment: The chemical in the skunklock is able to harm eyes for a longer time to permanently - which would qualify for great bodily injury.

Comment: Okay that sounds incredibly dangerous.

Comment: Yeah, based on the wording given above I'd have to agree with your conclusion. It's not concealed or camouflaged, it's not *designed* to cause bodily harm, and you could argue that there's no trigger mechanism. On the point of eye damage, considering you'd have to use a tool like an angle grinder to cut the shackle, it's unlikely your eyes would be anywhere near it so I think the risk of that is negligible.

If you consider the "spirit" of the law, then if the goal is to avoid hurting an unintended target (fire fighter, police, etc), I think this lock would not be considered a booby trap.

Comment: @Gogeta70 The 'spirit' of the law isn't really about innocent victims... The single most famous boobytrap case is Katko v. Briney (1971) where the Iowa supreme court held that deadly force is not justified even on criminal intruders in an unoccupied property. It wasn't about unintended targets -- Briney's trap worked perfectly and did exactly what it was supposed to, to the intended target, and it was still held to be illegal.

Comment: I find the distinction quite interesting and it's probably not really possible to know the outcome without testing it but again pointing to the wording of "designed to cause bodily harm"  It is clearly not designed to cause bodily harm but what if someone is allergic to the gas for example.  Would that just be a case of moral luck?   And to what end?   What if someone is startled by an alarm, trips, and hits their head?

Comment: Reading the [skunklock](https://www.skunklock.com/) website, particularly their FAQ makes me think they are simply an easy target for some future lawsuits.  They advertise it induces vomiting which I'm sure could easily be argued is bodily injury, and they make several arguments claiming it is not legally a booby trap by clearly misquoting US law (if this answer is correct anyway).

Comment: @jesse_b What did they misquote? They did say "protruded harm" when I think they meant "protracted" but that aside, I think their arguments are pretty sound, though I'm not convinced the law requires a trigger per-se, since it mentions sharpened stakes specifically, presumably referring to a tiger-trap or punji pit. On the other hand, a trap-door or cover that fails under weight probably does count as a triggering device, and if there's no cover on it, it's hardly a booby trap (any more than a fence topped with barbwire is...)

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Your answer says "triggered by any action of any unsuspecting person making contact with the device" it then lists examples of triggers but I would not interpret that as being limited to those examples. They also said that every law specifies "great bodily harm" when the federal law you quoted does not.  Also a well known purpose for the booby trap law is that first responders may legally perform the action that triggers them so their comment that it cannot easily be triggered is moot because a fireman may have to cut it off lawfully for some reason.

Comment: I guess I'm thinking "when triggered by any action" suggests that there is an action that causes the device to in some way activate or engage. A pressurized cylinder with no moving parts is hardly being "triggered" when you cut into it. Which would follow along with the Skunklock interpretation.  But I stand by my answer -- even if that's true, there isn't THAT much clear precedent so you could easily still get in some legal trouble even if you're eventually cleared.

Comment: Even a city worker may need to cut the lock off an abandoned bike.  These sorts of examples make the argument that the trigger cannot easily be triggered moot.  Trigger can be defined as "An event that precipitates other events." so cutting a pipe and releasing gas can be defined as a trigger, particularly when the gas was intentionally placed to be released upon that trigger.

Comment: As far as 'great' bodily injury, like I said, that's at least in the California code, so I don't think it's wild to go by that wording.  The USC I quoted covers a very narrow range of locations (federal facilities handling controlled substances), the California code is generally enforceable across the whole state.  Anyway, I'm not going to argue this. My answer is my answer.  Whether "cops need to cut your lock off" is a reason for this item to be illegal is outside my realm, and it's possibly unclear what "trigger" means in the law.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I don't question the wording of california law but their website says "all State statutes and regulations within the United States" and "We have identified three primary considerations for analyzing the legality of the sale and use of the SKUNKLOCK, in regards to whether it can reasonably be considered a “booby trap” by both Federal and State law"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150347/discussion-between-jesse-b-and-darth-pseudonym).